# Cannot retrieve previously fetched HashMap data

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a method that loops over an array of data grabbed from a websever every 5 seconds.

Everything works fine except values are never being updated even it's `key` was added in previous fetch, always keeps adding, which means

```
int value = myHashMapDB.get(key);
```

`value` always returns `null`.

`keys` in the array from server are always unique.

```
   private HashMap<String,Integer> myHashMapDB;

//call this method every five seconds
private void getFromSeverEveryFiveSeconds() {

     HashMap<String,Integer> myHashMapTEMP = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //declare/clear previous data 

    //use async and fetch some data from server with a unique key for each row        
     JSONObject json = fetchSomeDataJson();
     JSONObject cars = json.getJSONObject("cars");
     for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
         String key = cars.names().getString(i); //get key from JSON array fetched from server

         if(myHashMapDB != null){ //skip first time
             //ok, this not the first time so check if key exists from previous fetch

             int value = myHashMapDB.get(key);
             if(value != null){
                value = updateValue; //update value
                myHashMapTEMP.put(key,value); //put the value with the same key
                continue; //go to next loop
             }
         }


         //ok, key does not exists, add it

         int value = newValue;
         myHashMapTEMP.put(key,value); //put it with the key
     }

     //ok loop is done, lets finalize data

     if(myHashMapDB != null && myHashMapDB.size() != 0){ //if this is not the first time
         for (int value : myHashMapDB.values()) {
                //remove old ones. works fine!
         }
     }

     myHashMapDB = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //declare/clear previous data
     myHashMapDB.putAll(myHashMapTEMP); //copy all the data from current loop to the main HashMap.
     myHashMapTEMP = null; //clear the temporary HashMap data
}
```

Here is the source code without comments

```
private HashMap<String,Integer> myHashMapDB;

private void getFromSeverEveryFiveSeconds() {
     HashMap<String,Integer> myHashMapTEMP = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

     JSONObject json = fetchSomeDataJson();
     JSONObject cars = json.getJSONObject("cars");

     for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
         String key = cars.names().getString(i);

         if(myHashMapDB != null){
             int value = myHashMapDB.get(key);
             if(value != null){
                value = updateValue;
                myHashMapTEMP.put(key,value);
                continue;
             }
         }

         int value = newValue;
         myHashMapTEMP.put(key,value); 
     }

     if(myHashMapDB != null && myHashMapDB.size() != 0){
         for (int value : myHashMapDB.values()) {
                //remove old ones. works fine!
         }
     }

     myHashMapDB = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
     myHashMapDB.putAll(myHashMapTEMP);
     myHashMapTEMP = null;
}
```

Sample JSON data

```
{"totalcars":1,"cars":{"C87ED7":["????","","MAZDA","R8",-46.1685,167.833,0,0,0,"1421104212","0000",0,""]}}
```

Using above sample data `C87ED7` will be the key.

Comment: Where is newValue defined?  Also you need to define your hashmap using objects, rather than primitives  - e.g. HashMap<String, Integer>  (not int)

Comment: @spudone That's just an example, actual code is much complex.

Comment: @spudone `int` is an example too, in the real code I use a `class`. I have updated the code.

Comment: Where and how is `myHashMapDB` declared? The line you commented as `//declare/clear previous data` does **not** declare it.

Comment: I have done it on top `private HashMap<String,Integer> myHashMapDB;`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the name.

Comment: I think we'll need more complete code; maybe use a sample JSON string to mock it up.  The example isn't currently buildable.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding debug log statements at each step (log the json that was received async, log the key/value before you do each put, validate anything that might be null, etc)